# Numpy mean of all pairwise divisions between arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays of arbitrary length:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5]
```

I want the average of all fractions `x/y` where `x` is from `a` and `y` is from `b` i.e. `avg(1/4 + 1/5 + 2/4 + 2/5 +...) = 0.45` in this case.

I would like to avoid using loops, and stick to numpy functions. I have found a solution using `np.meshgrid`:

```
numerator = a
denominator = 1/b

pairs = np.array(np.meshgrid(numerator, denominator)).T.reshape(-1,2)
>>> array([[1.  , 0.25],
           [1.  , 0.2 ],
           [2.  , 0.25],
           [2.  , 0.2 ],
           [3.  , 0.25],
           [3.  , 0.2 ]])

fractions = np.multiply.reduce(pairs, axis=1)
>>> array([0.25, 0.2 , 0.5 , 0.4 , 0.75, 0.6 ])

result = np.mean(fractions)
>>> 0.45 # Correct
```

I would like to know if there is a more elegant (mathematical?) way of achieving the result I want. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: It seems like you really have a math problem, rather than a programming problem. The result you want is equal to the sum of the elements of `a`, times the sum of the reciprocals of the elements of `b`, divided by the total number of elements (which is the length of `a` times the length of `b`). You can prove this result by simply imagining the fractions grouped up according to the numerator.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because of the above reasoning - the solution is trivial once the problem is understood.

Comment: Seems I need to stop working so late, thanks for spelling it out for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first determine the sum of all items, and then divide that sum by the items in `b` to determine the mean:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> b = np.array([4,5])
>>> (a.mean() / b).mean()
0.45
```

The advantage of first calculating the mean of the numerators, is that this algorithm takes *linear* time (*O(|a| + |b|)*), instead of quadratic time (*O(|a|×|b|)*).

Answer (score 1):

```
numpy.divide.outer([1,2,3], [4,5]).flatten().mean()
Output: 0.45
```

The `divide.outer` here would create a 3x2 array of the first array elements divided by the second.

```
In [2]: numpy.divide.outer([1,2,3], [4,5])
Out[2]: 
array([[0.25, 0.2 ],
       [0.5 , 0.4 ],
       [0.75, 0.6 ]])
```

From there we just need to flatten and then take the average